# Title on center,Image on right corner in actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I am working on android app, I created the custom action bar.  But  It is not coming right. It is coming like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuuCG.jpg . I want image at the right corner.
I dont know why `android:gravity="end"` not working

Codes:

```
com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        /*Dynamically Load Image on ActionBar of the user.... Here R.drawable is extracted into ID from iconfile as string */
        Resources res = this.getResources(); 
        int resID = res.getIdentifier(this.iconFile, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.abs_message);
        com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView img = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_image);
        img.setImageResource(resID);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_name);
        txt.setText(sender);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

**abs_message.xml :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxHeight="1dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="75dp"
    android:paddingRight="48dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Joe miller"
    android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
     />


<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:border_color="#01DF01"
        app:border_width="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/online"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try - 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

1. In your **abs_message.xml** which define Action bar custom layout you set your base RelativeLayout with :

   **android:layout_width="wrap_content"**

   but you have to set to match_parent to fill action bar space :

   **android:layout_width="match_parent"**
2. In your CircularImageView you have to add :

   **android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"**

BTW : **android:gravity="end"** set gravity for image display in CircularImageView and not for CircularImageView in it's parent